# Why does the shifting of limits here have no impact

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

It is mentioned [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32) that,

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{2\pi} exp\left(z\cos(\theta) \right)d\theta = 2\pi I_0(z)
\end{equation}

whereas, in equation 30 of [this reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.09696#:%7E:text=In%20these%20applications%2C%20it%20is%20often%20useful%20to,probability%20distribution%20relative%20to%20the%20coordinate%20system%27s%20origin.), following integral was transformed to the same result,
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{2\pi} exp\left(z\cos(\theta - \phi) \right)d\theta = \int_{-\phi}^{2\pi-\phi} exp\left(z\cos(\theta') \right)d\theta'  =2\pi I_0(z),
\end{equation}

where $\phi$ is a constant.

I need to understand that why does the shifting operation impose no change in the result.

Following the operations above, can I say that [1](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32),

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(\theta)exp\left(z\cos(\theta - \phi) \right)d\theta = 2\pi I_1(z)
\end{equation}

Edit 1:

$I_n(z)$ is the n-th order modified Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: Might be helpful to distinguish the $\theta$ variable from the two sides. Let $\theta_{LHS}$ be the $\theta$ on the LHS, and $\theta_{RHS} = \theta_{LHS}-\phi$ be the one on the RHS. Then by substitution, $d\theta_{RHS} = d\theta_{LHS}$, the upper bound $\theta_{LHS}=2\pi$ becomes $\theta_{RHS} = 2\pi-\phi$, and the lower bound $\theta_{LHS}=0$ becomes $\theta_{RHS} = -\phi$.

Comment: What is $I_1(z)$?

Comment: @peterwhy : Thanks, I did the changes. I understand how the limits change, but why does the result is independent of the shift (phi in this case).

Comment: Then also you may split the RHS into two integrals to match your first equation:

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{-\phi}^{2\pi-\phi}\exp(z\cos\theta)\ d\theta &= \int_{-\phi}^0\exp(z\cos\theta)\ d\theta + \int_0^{2\pi-\phi}\exp(z\cos\theta)\ d\theta\\
&= \int_{2\pi-\phi}^{2\pi}\exp(z\cos\theta)\ d\theta + \int_0^{2\pi-\phi}\exp(z\cos\theta)\ d\theta\\
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\exp(z\cos\theta)\ d\theta 
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I realize I'm so dumb. Thanks @peterwhy.

Comment: @KB : It's the modified Bessel function of first kind and first order. Edited.

Comment: For the question about $I_1(z)$, after substitution $\theta_1 = \theta-\phi$, the LHS should become

$$\int_{-\phi}^{2\pi-\phi}\cos(\theta_1+\phi)\exp(z\cos\theta_1)\ d\theta_1$$

Even after shifting integration bounds, you still have to handle that $\cos(\theta_1+\phi)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question about $I_0(z)$: For the first equal sign, by substitution $\theta' = \theta-\phi$, $d\theta' = d\theta$, the upper bound $\theta=2\pi$ becomes $\theta' = 2\pi-\phi$, and the lower bound $\theta=0$ becomes $\theta' = -\phi$.

Then the second equal sign, you may split the LHS into two integrals to match your first equation:

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{-\phi}^{2\pi-\phi}\exp(z\cos\theta)\ d\theta &= \int_{-\phi}^0\exp(z\cos\theta)\ d\theta + \int_0^{2\pi-\phi}\exp(z\cos\theta)\ d\theta\\
&= \int_{2\pi-\phi}^{2\pi}\exp(z\cos\theta)\ d\theta + \int_0^{2\pi-\phi}\exp(z\cos\theta)\ d\theta\\
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\exp(z\cos\theta)\ d\theta 
\end{align*}$$

---

Second question about $I_1(z)$: After substitution $\theta_1 = \theta-\phi$, the LHS should become

$$\int_{-\phi}^{2\pi-\phi}\cos(\theta_1+\phi)\exp(z\cos\theta_1)\ d\theta_1$$

Even after shifting integration bounds, you still have to handle that $\cos(\theta_1+\phi)$.

Comment: We can split the integrals using, $$ \cos(\theta_1 + \phi) = \cos(\theta_1)\cos(\phi) - \sin(\theta_1)\sin(\phi) $$ The second integral will be zero cause of odd $\sin$ function and the first integral limits will be independent of $\phi$.

Comment: @NikhilSharma OK I think you are right about the $\sin\theta_1 \exp(z\cos\theta_1)$ part, integrating that over any $2\pi$ interval would give $0$.